# Oracle shell script - error on calling the variable using dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, oracle11g, ksh

Below is the code snippet from a little lengthy script. The below is used for extracting the DDL from of the output of RESULT1. But, it fail to generate the output and gives following error. Would be grateful if you could shed some light on as to what's wrong with the below.

Code :-

```
`RESULT1=`sqlplus -s 'system/'$DBSYS'@PROD'  2>/dev/null <<EOF
   set feedback off
   set heading off
   select view_name from dba_views where view_name like '%DB2%';
EOF`

VIEWS_DDL=`sqlplus -s 'system/'$DBSYS'@PROD'  2>/dev/null <<EOF|tail -1
   set feedback off heading off long 99999 linesize 1234 pages 1234
   spool $LOCSC/DB2_VIEWS_$RQNUM.sql
   select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','$RESULT1','DATA_OWNER') from dual;
   spool off
EOF``
```

When the script is run it should ideally generate the DDL for views in a location called through spool file which it does but, gives the below errors in the spool file.

Output :-

```
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "DB2_OPORTR..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "DB2_DGORDP..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "DB2_DGORDP..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "DB2_SOPOGI..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do it as two scripts or even two queries?

Comment: You can't plug in $RESULT1 into get_ddl because that's populated by the first script as a multiple line output with carriage returns. You would need to loop through each of the $RESULT1 lines that actually refer to a view, populate the view name into a variable, and use that in the second script. However the approach is wrong. Don't use shell for looping like this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex, Not sure if I can achieve it differently. Would be grateful if you can share any examples to do it better way.

Comment: select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW',view_name,owner) from dba_views where view_name like '%DB2%'; .. one script.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @PaulW. Can you share any examples on how can it be achieved. The goal is to extract the DDL for the views.

Comment: Thank you so much @PaulW. It really helped. Just testing the code as its giving a different error if called from the script. 

 cat DB2_VIEWS_TESTDIR.sql
ERROR:
ORA-16000: database or pluggable database open for read-only access
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6731
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6516
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOCK", line 378
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOCK", line 411
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPU$UTILITIES_INT", line 1738
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 1216

Comment: What is your database version? There's an 18c bug that throws this, for which there is a patch

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_ and _ksh_? I don't see any code in bash or ksh in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first call to SQL*Plus returns multiple values, which you're trying to use in the second call, where only one is expected.

You don't need two queries, you can combine them as:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW',view_name,'DATA_OWNER')
from dba_views
where view_name like '%DB2%';
```

Though you would want to restrict the query to the same user you're specifying in the function call, as:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW',view_name,'DATA_OWNER')
from dba_views
where owner = 'DATA_OWNER'
and view_name like '%DB2%';
```

or with just one reference, using the table column value in the function call too:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW',view_name,owner)
from dba_views
where owner = 'DATA_OWNER'
and view_name like '%DB2%';
```

You might want to look at [`set_transform_param`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_METADATA.html#GUID-0ACD6E3B-C699-469F-8CC3-32F9DA20CA60) to modify how the DDL is presented.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole. Really appreciate the quick help on the above sample. It really helped me work with the script but, currently I am facing a different lock error not sure why its giving an error. When I run it on database it gets the DDL output but, when ran through the script it gives the error I mentioned above.

Comment: What do you mean by 'on database'? Using a different client, or connecting to a different database? Maybe your PROD TNS alias is pointing to a standby?